# Css :last-child using on Laravel @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, css

On `Laravel` blade I'm using this code to iterate through a list which is filled by an array:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($prerequisites as $prerequisite)
        <li class="pre-course"
            style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
            <p>
                ...
            </p>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

on this my code each `<li>` have `border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;` and i'm trying to remove that on last child with `Css` by code:

```
ul li.pre-course:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

but it doesn't work and last child have border

Comment: Remove the inline style-tag in the element and set that border in your CSS-file instead. If you, for some strange reason, don't want to do that, try and change your css to: `border-bottom:none !important;`. Inline styles takes precedence over CSS, which is one of several  reasons not to use them.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks problem resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that's due to the inline style overriding the stylesheet CSS. Try to move the "regular" rule from inline to the stylesheet, like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($prerequisites as $prerequisite)
        <li class="pre-course">
            <p>
                ...
            </p>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
ul li.pre-course {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
ul li.pre-course:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

That way `:last-child` will overwrite the regular CSS rule

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Priority of in-line css is higher

```
    <li class="pre-course">
        <p>
            ...
        </p>
    </li>
```

Try this css

```
 ul li.pre-course:not(:last-child) {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 }
```